# Rolling file appender unable to make zip file

Tags: logging, log4j

i guess it might be a duplicate. but please help me with a solution.
My log4j configuration writes to the log file. But it fails to append it to a zip file. PFA my configuration. Please help me identify what I am missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="logging" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- <param name="threshold" value="debug"/>  -->  
        <param name="file" value="/var/MyConfigurations/mobile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <rollingPolicy name = "logging" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="myfolder.log.%d.log.gz" />
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The log message pattern -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
          <logger name="com.myfolderlink" additivity="true">
                <level value="warn"/>
                <appender-ref ref="logging" />
        </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="logging" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `name = "logging"` is necessary on `<rollingPolicy>` element. Could the addition of this made your rollingPolicy ineffective? Try removing it.

Also org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender resides on separate jar apache-log4j-extras. Make sure this jar is included in your classpath